# How to fix android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/SM.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
private void createPdf() {

    File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
    File pdfFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "SM.pdf");
    try {
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));enter code here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // close the document
    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF is created!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   // openGeneratedPDF();
}
```

logout:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/SM.pdf exposed beyond app through `Intent.getData()`

Comment: Check this link..https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/4657385

Comment: Use File provider to open the files..

Answer (score 0):

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder(); 

StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Comment: When added that @Vishal Bhut

Comment: Tack screen shoot for activity and save as pdf file @Zun

Comment: Not you, I meant to ask @vishal